# Linq OrderBy doesn't return expected results

Tags: c#, linq

This may be a tiny miss attention issue:

```
  myColl.OrderByDescending(item => item.myCollItemCreationDate)
.GroupBy(item => new { item.Id, item.ItemType, item.ChannelName })
          .Select(res => new ChannelRowUi(res.ToList())
                  {
                      ChannelName = res.Key.ChannelName,
                      ItemType = res.Key.ItemType.ToString() 
                  });
```

But then I understood I was mistaken, as the grouping messed the order.

I changed to:

```
myColl.GroupBy(item => new { item.Id, item.ItemType, item.ChannelName })
      .Select(res => new ChannelRowUi(res.ToList())
              {
                  ChannelName = res.Key.ChannelName,
                  ItemType = res.Key.ItemType.ToString() 
              })
              .OrderByDescending(item => item.myCollItemCreationDate);
```

But I still get the final result unsorted by creation date.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That really looks like 1) it shouldn't compile (which is another issue) or 2) `CreationDate` of `ChannelRowUi` was not set (which would explain the OrderByDescending "not working"...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the order of the select and the OrderBy.
Remember it is a chain of functions, the next function always operates on the result of the previous one in the chain.
When you have the orderBy last you are ordering the result of the Select.
In the select you are constructing new ChannelRowUi objects which probably all get the same CreationDate, can't say for sure as you haven't shown the ChannelRowUi constructor.

Answer (score 2):

```
myColl
     .GroupBy(item => new { item.Id, item.ItemType, item.ChannelName })
     .OrderByDescending(item => item.CreationDate)
     .ToList() 
     .Select(res =>

            new ChannelRowUi(res.ToList())
            {
                ChannelName = res.Key.ChannelName,

                ItemType = res.Key.ItemType.ToString()
            })
```

Comment: Can you describe your answer for me, please

Comment: in this case you are ordering the result in your database and retrieving it in memory and then creating a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you mus call the ToList command

Also , Please try to avoid ToList.

If you have Big Data - its is wrong to use ToList.

you should use Deferred Ecxecution

first you got to do the orderby and then select.

Comment: @EladBenda sorry I meant baz1nga